# oracle function error pls-00103

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I receive the following error when I compile this function:

> Error(19,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     loop

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION EXP_NOW
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  cprod   NUMBER;
  dexp    DATE;
  prodexp NUMBER := 0;
  CURSOR prodsd IS
    SELECT cod_prod,
           dat_exp
    FROM   produse;
BEGIN
    OPEN prodsd;

    LOOP
        FETCH prodsd INTO cprod, dexp;

        EXIT WHEN prodsd%NOTFOUND;

        IF ( dexp <= SYSDATE ) THEN
          prodexp := cprod;
        END IF;
    EXIT LOOP;

    CLOSE prodsd;

    RETURN prodexp;
END;
```

Can someone help me? This is so frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use `END LOOP` instead of `EXIT LOOP` ? Basically you use `LOOP` and `END LOOP` to open/close your loop structure; you can use `EXIT WHEN` inside it then.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot buddy! Do you know what would be the reason for this behavior? I also have a stored procedure in a package which takes no parameters and I get the same error.

Comment: It's because `END LOOP` is how you terminate a block that starts with `LOOP`. `EXIT` (without the LOOP) is how you force an exit from a LOOP that you're inside. Share and enjoy.